# Android gradle apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Tags: android

I was just wondering why that line of code exists in my gradle configuration

```
Android gradle apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: how is "com.android.application" related to iOS? iOS is Apple, Android is not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Gradle](https://gradle.org/) is a general-purpose build system. It uses plugins to teach it how to build different types of software. `com.android.application` is a Gradle plugin that teaches Gradle how to build Android applications, just as `com.android.library` is a plugin that teaches Gradle how to build Android library projects. There are many plugins available for Gradle, to teach it how to build other sorts of systems or augment other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

As describe in the official website:The first line in the build configuration applies the Android plugin for
Gradle to this build and makes the android block available to specify
 Android-specific build options.